# How to show appropriate message on multiple notification click

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

My Application deals with Push notification and am showing multiple notification in status bar by using

```
notificationmanager.notify(id, notification);
```

where id is dynamic int. Now I want to get the "id" of the notification of the clicked notification in the status bar. Am passing the "id" by

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("notifyId", id);
```

But it always returns the "id" of the latest received notification. How can I get the "id" of the appropriate clicked notification ?

Code used to show notification:

```
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int i = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;

    // Set Notification Title
    String strtitle = getString(R.string.notificationtitle);
    // Set Notification Text
    String strtext = getString(R.string.notificationtext);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, strtext, when);

    // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("text", message);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notifyId", i);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(MyActivity.this, "Title",
            message, intent);

    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationmanager.notify(i, notification);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the link between `notificationIntent` and `notificationmanager` -- not sure that that matters, but it'd help me help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change flag from `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`
2. Use different second parameter when you create your PendingIntent